# Error: Uncaught Expected the HTML form element or the style selector of form

Tags: reactjs, forms, netlify

I've set up my contact page (with React) to work with Netlify's form submission API, however I'm receiving the following error:

I figure it's either something wrong with my html or the way I've sent the data. However I've done this in line with the documentation as best I can - albeit it's difficult to find working examples.

***react-dom.production.min.js:52 Uncaught Expected the HTML form element or the style selector of form***

Would really appreciate any guidance on this, thanks.

Here's my Contact function -

```
const encode = (data) => {
  return Object.keys(data)
      .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
      .join("&");
}

function Contact() {

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const handleName = e => {
      setName(e.currentTarget.value);
      };

    const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
    const handleSubject = e => {
        setSubject(e.currentTarget.value); 
    }

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const handleEmail = e => {
        setEmail(e.currentTarget.value);
    };

    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const handleMessage = e => {
        setMessage(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const sendEmail = e => {

    fetch("/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: encode({ "form-name": "contact", ...useState })
    })
      .then(() => alert("Success!"))
      .catch(error => alert(error));

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log((name), (email), (message)); 
  };


  return (

    <>

    <div className="sub-wrap">

    <h3 className="small-text">Call me on the telephone</h3>

    <h3 className="numb">07879 *** ***</h3>

    <h3 className="small-text">Or punch your deets into the form below</h3>

    </div>

    <div className="form-wrap">

    <form onSubmit={ sendEmail } >

        <div className="input-wrap">

            <legend>Name</legend>
          <input
            value={ name }
            type='text'
            name='name'
            onChange={ handleName }
          />
        </div>

        <div className="input-wrap">   
          <legend>Email</legend>
            <input
              value={ email }
              type='email'
              name='email'
              onChange={ handleEmail }
            />
        </div>

        <div className="input-wrap">  
          <legend>Subject</legend>
            <input
              value={ subject }
              type='subject'
              name='subject'
              onChange={ handleSubject }
            />
        </div>

        <div className="input-wrap">  
          <legend>Message</legend>
            <textarea
                        className="msg-box"
              value={ message }
              name='message'
              onChange={ handleMessage }
                />
        </div>

            <button className='input-button' type='submit'>Send</button>

          </form>

        </div>

        </>

    );
  }

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by changing the button to an input, despite the Netlify docs advising to use button.